# How to Improve jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a validation and it's working fine, but I have so many repeat code and can´t find a way to improve it. Here is:

```
function validate( active ){

    if( active[0].id === "mod_formSteps-1" ){

        var $inputs = $("#formSteps-1 :input:not(:submit)");
        var value = true;

        $inputs.each(function() {
            if( $(this).val().length < 1 || $(this).hasClass("error")){
                value = false;
            }
        });
        return value;   
    }
    else if( active[0].id === "mod_formSteps-2" ){

        var $inputs = $("#formSteps-2 :input:not(:submit)");
        var value = true;

        $inputs.each(function() {
            if( $(this).val().length < 1 || $(this).hasClass("error")){
                value = false;
            }
        });
        return value;   
    }
    ...

    ...
    else{
        alert("something is wrong");                
    }           
    return true;
}
```

Now I have four if that are the same just change the paramater `"mod_formStepsN"` and `"#formSteps-1"`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not give them all a common class and use that instead of IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more like this

```
function validate(active) {
    var numb   = active.prop('id').split('-').pop(),
        inputs = $("#formSteps-"+numb+" :input:not(:submit)"),
        value  = true;

    inputs.each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length < 1 || $(this).hasClass("error")) {
            value = false;
        }
    });

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
function validate( active ){
    if(active[0].id != "")
    {
        var $inputs = $("#"+active[0].id+":input:not(:submit)");
        var value = true;

        $inputs.each(function() {
            if( $(this).val().length < 1 || $(this).hasClass("error")){
                value = false;
            }
        });
        return value;
    }
    else{
        alert("something is wrong");                
    }           
    return true;
}
```